# How can I clear only last floated block

Tags: html, css-float

I have multiple floated blocks. Is it possible to specify which block should be cleared?

Check following structure:

```
+------------+ +--------------------+
|            | |+--------+ +-------+|
| float:left | ||fl left | |fl left|| 
|            | |+--------+ +-------+|
|            | |+------------------+|
|            | ||                  ||
|            | || block that clears||
|            | || prev 2  floated  ||
|            | || blocks but doesn't|  
|            | || clear first fl.  ||
|            | || block            ||
|            | |+------------------+|
|            | +--------------------+
+------------+
```

in html:

```
<div class="floated-left-column">
   left column content
</div>
<div class="right-column">
   <div>
       <div class="float-left">...</div>
       <div class="float-left">...</div>
   </div>
   <div>
        This block should clear only ".float-left" blocks (not ".floated-left-column")
   </div>
   <div>
        Here is some content
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you got some code that you've been working with?

Answer (score 0):

You need to float the parent block on the right hand side "left" as well. You can float and clear in sub-containers and the parent container will not clear.

I see you added an example now. Float left the DIV "right-column"

Answer (score 0):

This is basic HTML/CSS layout. Take a look at [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cMjUj/).

When you clear a float, it will usually only clear floats within the same container, or lower. This is why when you put something with `clear: both` into your container at the top level it clears *everything*.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it with following html. Thank you for your help. Is it ok solution for my problem (it works but I don't know it works in other browsers and etc.)?

```
<div class="floated-left-column">
   left column content
</div>
<div class="right-column">
   <div class="floated-left-with-100-precent-width">
       <div>
           <div class="float-left">...</div>
           <div class="float-left">...</div>
       </div>
       <div class="clearfix"></div>
   </div>

   <div>
        This block should clear only ".float-left" blocks (not ".floated-left-column")
   </div>
   <div>
        Here is some content
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is probably pretty easy to do using [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html). If you're designing a new site from scratch, bootstrap's an excellent place to start anyway..

Comment: True, however this doesn't answer the question.